# Magento connect to Redis from different server

Tags: magento-1.9, redis

I need help here to configure Magento local.xml file. I have two server here. One is running the magento and the other one is running Redis. Basically, it just work fine if we run redis on the same server with magento, right. But I have problem to connect redis from different server. How to configure it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about configuring redis to accept connections from the outside and not Magento.

Comment: wat i mean is...i want to connect magento to redis wich located at different server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't encourage a server configuration of 1 web server and 1 cache server; you are needlessly adding cost, complexity, insecurity and performance overhead.

If you have 10 web servers saturating the network/memory resources of Redis, then it may make sense. But there's simply no reason for an entire server to be dedicated to Redis at such a small scale.

--

However, to answer your question, you need to

1. Configure the Redis daemon to listen on a non-local interface, not Unix socket
2. Change your `local.xml` to connect by IP/port not socket

The actual configuration of each is beyond the scope of Magento.SE

Comment: Upvoted for the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

This is my config, redisserver - hostname, u can use just ip address if u want.

```
<session_save>db</session_save>
    <redis_session>                       <!-- All options seen here are the defaults -->
        <host>redisserver</host>            <!-- Specify an absolute path if using a unix socket -->
        <port>6379</port>
        <password></password>             <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
        <timeout>2.5</timeout>            <!-- This is the Redis connection timeout, not the locking timeout -->
        <persistent></persistent>         <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
        <db>0</db>                        <!-- Redis database number; protection from accidental loss is improved by using a unique DB number for sessions -->
        <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  <!-- Set to 0 to disable compression (recommended when suhosin.session.encrypt=on); known bug with strings over 64k: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/18 -->
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              <!-- gzip, lzf, lz4 or snappy -->
        <log_level>1</log_level>               <!-- 0 (emergency: system is unusable), 4 (warning; additional information, recommended), 5 (notice: normal but significant condition), 6 (info: informational messages), 7 (debug: the most information for development/testing) -->
        <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>                 <!-- maximum number of processes that can wait for a lock on one session; for large production clusters, set this to at least 10% of the number of PHP processes -->
        <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       <!-- seconds to wait for a session lock in the frontend; not as critical as admin -->
        <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
        <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>                 <!-- Lifetime of session for non-bots on the first write. 0 to disable -->
        <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>          <!-- Lifetime of session for bots on the first write. 0 to disable -->
        <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    <!-- Lifetime of session for bots on subsequent writes. 0 to disable -->
        <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>                 <!-- Disable session locking entirely. -->
        <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>                      <!-- Set the minimum session lifetime -->
        <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>                 <!-- Set the maximum session lifetime -->
    </redis_session>
 <cache>
        <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>redisserver</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
            <database>0</database> <!-- Redis database number; protection against accidental data loss is improved by not sharing databases -->
            <password></password> <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures; a value of 1 will not retry after the first failure -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration; phpredis does not currently support setting read timeouts -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf, lz4 (as l4z) and snappy -->
            <use_lua>0</use_lua> <!-- Set to 1 if Lua scripts should be used for some operations -->
        </backend_options>
    </cache>
```